# Split a Date/Time String into Tokens with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I am trying to break a date format string (and an input date string) into parts (tokens).

A date format can use any separating character between tokens, as long as the tokens are valid. The date/time will be parsed into the format and the non-alphanumeric characters will carry over into the output string. I would like to strip the tokens from both the date/time format string and the input date/time string.

**I need to split a string on all sets of non-alphanumeric characters**

For example, let's say my date format string is:

```
'dddd, MMMM D, YYYY h:mm A'
```

I would like to have an array of all of the date/time tokens in the string. My output should be:

```
['dddd', 'MMMM', 'D', 'YYYY', 'h', 'mm', 'A']
```

I tried a couple of attempts, but I still cannot wrap my head around how to do this. I was able to come up with the regex:

```
[^\w]|[_]
```

which should match any character not present in `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` as the first alternative or match `_` literally as the second alternative.

I have tested this regex and it does work, yet how can I use it properly?

I tried to use:

```
var format_tokens = display_format.match(/[^\w]|[_]/g);
```

..which, of course, returned me:

```
format_tokens = [",", " ", " ", ",", " ", " ", ":", " "];
```

..which should have been obvious...

So how do I get the inverse? How can I get the desired result of:

```
format_tokens = ['dddd', 'MMMM', 'D', 'YYYY', 'h', 'mm', 'A']
```

?

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use [str.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)?

Comment: @william.taylor.09 they're not splitting on just commas, but also the space and colon.

Comment: @DanielFlint, thank you, oversight on my part. In this case, OP could replace all spaces and colons with commas and then split, but this seems silly for something a regexp could do.

Comment: @william.taylor.09 Unfortunately your suggested split would not work for all cases. A user can define their own date format using any valid date tokens and any non-alphanumeric characters they want. If they really wanted to, they could even use `dddd?!MMMM-!-D,@YYYY#$h:mm*A` which I would need to return the same as the example above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to match alphanumeric characters and split/exclude on everything else then, right? Which would be `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

this:

```
'dddd, MMMM D, YYYY h:mm A'.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g)
```

returns:

```
["dddd", "MMMM", "D", "YYYY", "h", "mm", "A"]
```

Comment: Hahaha! How could I oversee this? Thank you for the fast response. I just tested this in regex101 and it works exactly as I wanted although I still can't accept your answer for another 5 minutes!